# Dropdown menu item reversal

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and my code looks as below

### In HTML:

```
<select name="dropdown" onChange="javascript: alertUser()" >
<option value="0" selected>Eat</option>
<option value="1">Work</option>
<option value="2">Sleep</option>
<option value="3" >Enjoy</option>
```

### In javascript:

```
function alertUser()
{
    confirm("Are you sure?");
}
```

---

Now, here is my problem.

When I select an element from dropdown, it will pop up confirmation dialogue "Are you Sure?".  If I click Ok, the selection should change to selected value. If I cancel, the selected value should reset back to previously selected value in dropdown list.

Could anyone please help me to solve the problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var select = document.getElementsByName('dropdown')[0];
    var lastselected = select.value;
    select.onchange = function () {
        var newselected = select.value;
        if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
            lastselected = newselected
            return true;
        }
        select.value = lastselected;
    }
};
```

I added onload to it so it will run when page loads. I removed your inline js, more clean. So your html would be:

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="0" selected>Eat</option>
    <option value="1">Work</option>
    <option value="2">Sleep</option>
    <option value="3">Enjoy</option>
</select>
```

### **[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jeNR7/1/)**

Comment: Hi Sergio, I tried this in my code and it does not work! I tried both in Chrome as well as Firefox.

Comment: @user2669956, does it work in the demo? be sure to include this code after your html, like before the `</body>` tag.

Comment: It probably didn't work for him (on his page) because you didn't make your code run on load. Sure, in jsFiddle it runs on load but if you put that code onto a page, it will not.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, if you read my comment you see I suggested to add script in the end of body. That will work.

Comment: @JoeSimmons, anyway it's a possibility so I added it to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, sorry didn't see that. Yeah he probably didn't do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using the 'selectedIndex' method.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetenfold/UjYg2/

---

html

```
<select name="dropdown">
    <option value="0" selected>Eat</option>
    <option value="1">Work</option>
    <option value="2">Sleep</option>
    <option value="3">Enjoy</option>
</select>
```

---

JavaScript

```
function addEvent(elem, type, func) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(type, func, false);
    } else if (elem.attachEvent) {
        elem.attachEvent('on' + type, func);
    }
}

addEvent(window, 'load', function () {

    var select = document.getElementsByName('dropdown')[0],
        last = select.selectedIndex;
    addEvent(select, 'change', function () {
        if( confirm('Are you sure?') ) {
            last = select.selectedIndex;
        } else {
            select.selectedIndex = last;
        }
    });

});
```